# How to make JRE, compiler and build path of a Maven project become compatible in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a Maven project in which I need to set the following in POM file:

```
<properties>
    <camunda.external-task-client.version>7.17.0</camunda.external-task-client.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

The version of my Java is 11:

```
openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.15+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I encountered two warnings in eclipse:

1. *The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 11 is used Compiler Compliance JRE Compiler Compliance Problem*.
2. *Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.8. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.*

I searched and found out that I should change "compiler compliance level" from "windows -> preferences -> java", and I changed it to 1.8, as following.

[image]

However, the warning still remains.

Could anyone please help me regarding this. I have low experience in Java and Maven.

Comment: The proper way is to install java 8 and tell eclipse about it.

Comment: Make sure a Java 8 JDK is configured in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_.